# NuxtJs - Call Plugin in another plugin - vue-gtag

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, nuxt.js, gtag.js

I have integrated a Google Analytics component for Nuxt in a plugin :

I'm looking for how to call the $gtag global var instantiate by the gtag component, in another component.

In the target plugin I've tried :

```
export default ({ app, env, $gtag }) => {
....
}
```

or :

```
export default ({ app, env, gtag }) => {
....
}
```

or :

```
export default ({ env, app: {gtag} }) => {
....
}
```

It's always undefined.

**Somebody have an idea how to do that ?**

gtag-plugin.client.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueGtag from 'vue-gtag'

export default ({ app, env }) => {   

  Vue.use(VueGtag, {
    config: { env.gaIdProd },
    bootstrap: getGDPR === 'true',
    appName: 'xxx',
    enabled: getGDPR === 'true',
    pageTrackerScreenviewEnabled: true
  }, app.router)
}
```

Comment: you can just import it directly, because the the plugins are loaded like an array. I saw a snippet about moving indices. but in this case just `import gtag from 'gtag-plugin.client'` should work?

Comment: Is your second plugin called after the `gtag-plugin`? i.e declared after it in the `nuxt.config.js`?

Comment: Maybe it's better to use a `@nuxtjs/google-gtag` package.